# Drawing a line, drawing a list of lines... Why doesn't the latter work?

Tags: c#, 3d, xna, render, monogame

Drawing a line:

```
foreach (Line line in lineList) //Draw all lines in lineList
{
    if(line.V)//Is the current line visible?
    {
        Globals.graphics.GraphicsDevice.SetVertexBuffer(line.L);
        foreach (EffectPass pass in line.E.CurrentTechnique.Passes)
        {
            pass.Apply();
            Globals.graphics.GraphicsDevice.DrawPrimitives(PrimitiveType.LineStrip, 0, line.L.VertexCount - 1);
        }
    }
}
```

(`line.L`is a Vertex Buffer)

Drawing a cube:

```
foreach (Cube cube in cubeList)
{
    if (cube.V)
    {
        foreach (VertexBuffer line in cube.LB)//Draw each line in the cube
        {
            Globals.graphics.GraphicsDevice.SetVertexBuffer(line);
            foreach (EffectPass pass in cube.E.CurrentTechnique.Passes)
            {
                pass.Apply();
                Globals.graphics.GraphicsDevice.DrawPrimitives(PrimitiveType.LineStrip, 0, line.VertexCount - 1);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The first one works, the second one doesn't.
The code for drawing a cube is basically identical to the code for drawing a line.
The notable difference here between a line and a cube is that the cube has a list of vertexbuffers. This adds a simple foreach into the code for drawing the cube.

This altered line drawing code for drawing the first line strip in the cube works:

```
foreach (Line line in lineList) //Draw all lines in lineList
{
    if(line.V)//Is the current line visible?
    {
        Globals.graphics.GraphicsDevice.SetVertexBuffer(cubeList.First().LB.First());
        foreach (EffectPass pass in line.E.CurrentTechnique.Passes)
        {
            pass.Apply();
            Globals.graphics.GraphicsDevice.DrawPrimitives(PrimitiveType.LineStrip, 0, cubeList.First().LB.First().VertexCount - 1);
        }
    }
}
```

For the above code, I just set the vertex buffer to the first in the cube's vertex buffer list (which is `cube.LB`)

I can't figure out what the problem is with the code for drawing the cube...

The vertexbuffers in `cube` are defined as new `VertexBuffer(Globals.graphics.GraphicsDevice, typeof(VertexPositionColor), 10, BufferUsage.WriteOnly);`The 10 in that code varies, because the cube is drawn with 4 different line strips.
The first, with 10 vertices, is a linestrip for the upper face of the cube, one of the edges for going to the bottom part and the bottom face.
There are 3 more buffers, with 2 vertices each. They are the remaining three edges.

[image]

I can't find the problem with the code for drawing the cube. When "manually" inputting the vertexbuffers for the cube in the code for drawing the lines, they are drawn correctly. That indicates that there isn't a problem with the list of vertexbuffers or the vertexbuffers in the cube class...

Comment: I know this is not a code review question but rather than putting a comment next to the `line.V` code, why not just call the property `line.Visible`?

Comment: What exactly does not work? Btw, it should be way more efficient to use a single vertex buffer as a line list rather than several buffers with line strips.